# BuddyPress password security on sign-up form

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm using a registration only BuddyPress site. I noticed that there is no minimum lenght or complexity on the password field of the BuddyPress sign-up form. One character as a password is acepted...

I searched for hours and hours but can't find a solution. Any idea how to make it safer at sign-up? There are after sign-up plugins but that is not what I want. I want users to make a strong password at sign-up.

Comment: Check out the [registration_errors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors) hook. It is used to create your registration validation rules.

Comment: Actually, in BuddyPress you'd use the `bp_signup_validate` hook. The `registration_errors` hook is for WordPress.

Comment: Thanks Henry. I will look into that hook.